# Caliburn.Micro DisplayRootViewFor throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro

I have the following code in my Bootstrapper:

```
private SimpleContainer container;

protected override void Configure()
{
  container = new SimpleContainer();
  container.Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();
  container.PerRequest<InitialViewModel>();  
}

protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
{
  return container.GetInstance(service, key);
}

protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
{
  return container.GetAllInstances(service);
}

protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
{
  container.BuildUp(instance);
}
```

In the OnStartup method, I call the `DisplayRooViewFor` method:

```
protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{ 
  DisplayRootViewFor<InitialViewModel>();
}
```

This is the InitialViewModel:

```
    private IEventAggregator eventAggregator;    

    public InitialViewModel(IEventAggregator ea) 
    {
      eventAggregator = ea;
    }
```

Unfortunately, it throws a *NullReferenceException*:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   Caliburn.Micro.Platform.dll but was not handled in user code

I checked the source code of CM and used the same code to test it:

```
  protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
      var viewModel = IoC.GetInstance(typeof(InitialViewModel), null);
      var view = ViewLocator.LocateForModel(viewModel, null, null);
      ViewModelBinder.Bind(viewModel, view, null);

      var activator = viewModel as IActivate;
      if (activator != null)
        activator.Activate();

      DisplayRootViewFor<InitialViewModel>();
    }
```

Strangely, there was no Exception at those lines. Both *view* and *viewmodel* have reference, and the constructor of *InitialView* gets called, but when it reaches and calls `DisplayRootViewFor`, it still throws an exception.

What should I change?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My container was missing a critical component:

```
container.Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing between SimpleContainer and MEF injection. You should only use one of them.

**MEF**:
If your InitialViewModel should use MEF for constructor injection, you have to create a Bootstrapper to deal with it, like in this [post](http://hintdesk.com/c-wpf-mvvm-databinding-2014/). Remember to Export your InitialViewModel and remove SimpleContainer Code.

**SimpleContainer**
Or you remove MEF (by simply removing ImportingConstructor-Attribute), the SimpleContainer will take the Job.

Your InitialViewModel should inherit Caliburn.Micro Screen class if it's attached with main window.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. Unfortunately, removing the attribute and inheriting from Screen does not solve the issue, the exception is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize(); method needs to be called in your Bootstrapper CTOR.